# Identifying my late father's D&D stuff found in the attic

Tags: product-identification, odnd

I recently found a box of *Dungeons & Dragons* stuff in the attic of my father's home. In addition to an old boxed set of *Dungeons & Dragons* (the *Men and Magic* booklet mentions hobbits and ents), there's a plethora of other materials that I couldn't readily get more information about.

Below are some images of a few of the items in the box and the boxed set itself. I also found miniatures which I believe go with the game in some way. (Also I think the miniatures are lead due to their age and softness.)

I'm investigating these because I want to try to better understand my father when he was a young man. (He would have been 14 or 15 years old in 1974). He hadn't shared this part of himself with me; I would have loved to play this or a newer version of *D&D* with him before he passed away.

The quality of the photos is awful, but I will try to improve that shortly.

Here are the titles of the found items:

- *Dungeons & Dragons*, Rules for Fantastic Medieval Wargames Campaigns with Paper and Pencil and Miniature Figures Gygax & Arneson 3-Volume Set Published by Tactical Studies Rules Price $10.00 (Including three booklets, correction sets and item/weapon/monster lists)
- *The Ringbearer* by Dan Bress and Ed Konstant Illustrated by Wendall Hill
- *Kranor-Ril* Issue #1 (with an editorial by Chip Charnley, Editor): 'The Vadhagh' A New Class of Character As Developed from The Chronicles of Corum Vol. 1-3

**What exactly are these items?**

[image: D&D Box] [image: The Ringbearer][image: Kranor-Ril][image: The Vadhagh][image: Kranor-Ril #2]

Comment: Hi there jagd, thank you for sharing this with us. It would be most helpful if you could specify what you are looking to get out of this apart from "more information", although I'm sure the good people here will provide what they know.

Comment: White cover... your dad was an OG role-player, one of the pioneers.

Comment: Ed K is my father. We played these games for a long time at Little Soldier in Wheaton and then Rockville *(and in our home) with many. One of my earliest jobs was putting those booklets together in the basement. Yes, some of this is worth quite a bit considering they were pennies to make (still a fortune for some of us in the mid 70s). Who was your dad? Be well.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your father's copy of *Men and Magic* was issued somewhere between between the first and third printing, as shown [here](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/setpages/original.html) in the summary of the early editions.  The "[Man on the Horse](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/setpages/setscans/box3rd.jpg)" illustration was replaced by a [lone Fighting Man illustration](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/setpages/setscans/book1v3+.jpg) somewhere between the third and fourth printing. (That's the one in my set).

The Kranor-Ril adventure looks familiar, but I am having trouble placing it in my memory.  @[JohnDallman points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147178/identifying-my-late-fathers-dd-stuff-found-in-the-attic/147184#comment375712_147184) that Kranor-Ril looks like one of the early D&D fanzines.  @[HeyICanChan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147178/identifying-my-late-fathers-dd-stuff-found-in-the-attic/147184?noredirect=1#comment375763_147184) has found some more information on it [here](https://archive.org/stream/GIGO_4-1975-09-21/GIGO_4-1975-09-21_djvu.txt). (Warning, some strong language, scroll down about half way down the page).

D&D (originally) didn't come with lead figures, or indeed any miniatures.  People bought the miniatures separately, either from TSR/The Dungeon Hobby shop, or from a local game or hobby shop.  Most of my own figures from that era are lead.

*The Ringbearer* game [is rather rare](http://www.boardgame.de/reviews/ringbear.htm) with only 6,000 printed; it may be worth something to a collector.  (@Yakk offers that it looks to be first edition - only 1,000 of those were printed).

> "The Ringbearer - a wargame in which 4 - 10 players use dice and
>   old-time school fantasy miniatures to either capture the "Great Ring"
>   for the forces of evil, or destroy it by delivering it to the "Crack
>   of Darkness".

Comment: Kranor-Ril looks very much like a fanzine to me. There were quite a few early D&D fanzines, although I don't know anything about this one.

Comment: That actually looks like a first edition Ringbearer (1000 printed)

Comment: @JohnDallman The mimeographed sheets hit me sorta hard with the nostalgia wave ...

Comment: @HeyICanChan You are the goods, man! Thanks!  I have not been able to search some of my various sites due to current location, so thank you very much for that!

Comment: Thank you everyone for the additional information and links to further readings. It is enlightening and brings me great joy to think that my father was once the kind of boy to subscribe to a d&d fanzine, spending $2 for 6 issues. I even found a custom map drawn by him, inserted into one of the more delicate/well-loved issues of Kranor-Ril.

Answer (score 8):

The D&D is the original edition of the set.  If it's in a white box, it's pretty rare and worth money to some collectors.  If it is a grey box, it is one of the first printings and even more rare.  I can't tell from the picture if the box is grey or white, but my guess is it's the white box. If it contains the original dice, even better.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.